# Use BeautifulSoup to extract ID and report pairs and return a dictionary keyed on ID with values being the reports

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I'm new in Python programming and I wanna use BeautifulSoup to extract the case ID and EKG report pairs from a html file and return as a dictionary keyed on ID with values being the reports.

I write the following code but it is frustrating:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

def extractReports(filename):
report = {}

soup3 = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(filename))
txt = soup3.get_text()

for row in txt:
    report[row[0]].append(row[1:])
return report
```

Below is the part of the original copy of html file and I wanna something like

`{'344':'|Normal sinus rhythm|Right bundle branch block|Abnor', '345':'|Normal sinus rhythm|Left axis deviation','346':'|Normal sinus rhythm|Normal ECG|When compared with E'....}`

Can you please help me to fix/improve my code? thanks very much

[image]

Comment: What is the result now?

Comment: If this is the original html file then you have a problem and I would not use BS.  BS needs tags to help build a tree that you then use the tags to identify the parts of the tree you need.  When I first saw this I thought it would be easy because you would have something like for tr in table, for td in tr etc but if this is an html page with complicated design you may need to just do some text handling can you post more of the page - I want to see what kind of container is holding the text you have in brackets

Comment: Please provide the exactly HTML for help you.

Comment: Oh I see we need to see the html code not a graphic image of the page

Answer (score 2):

Without having the html source, it looks like you probably want something more like:

```
def extractReports(filename):
    report = {}
    soup3 = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(filename))
    txt = soup3.findall("tr")
    for row in txt:
        if some_condition:
              children = txt.findChildren()
              for child in children:
                   '''check if key/value, then add to dict'''


     return report
```

The keys here are two parts: first, use `findall()` to get all the rows in the page, then filter for those rows that are the ones you want.
Once you have the rows, use `findChildren()` to get the actual contents of `<td>`'s that you need to fill out the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def extract_reports(url):
    pg = requests.get(url)
    bs = BeautifulSoup(pg.content)
    reports = {}
    for row in bs.findAll("tr"):
        cells = [cell.text for cell in row.findAll("td")]
        try:
            reports[int(cells[0])] = cells[1]
        except (IndexError, ValueError):
            pass
    return reports
```